# How do I access a class' method from another class' method in c++

Tags: c++, class

So I have had this problem for a while now, and it's putting quite a damper on my work.  I'm no professional at C++ but I have been using it for a while now.

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib> // makes random way better by using time as a seed
#include <ctime>   // makes random way better by using time as a seed
//#include "Reference.h"
#include "Ref.cpp"
using namespace std;

///--Declarations--\\\

Assets assets;
TextPlay textplay;
///----------------\\\

int main() {
    assets.editConsoleState(true);

    ///----Console---\\\

    while (assets.consoleState() == true)) {
        textplay.consoleRefresh();
        textplay.makeCommand();
    }
    ///--------------\\\

    return 0;
}
```

Ref.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib> // makes random way better by using time as a seed
#include <ctime>   // makes random way better by using time as a seed
using namespace std;

class Assets
{
public:
    void editConsoleState(bool newstate)
    {
        isConsole = newstate;
    }

    bool consoleState()
    {
        bool state;
        state = isConsole;
        return state;
    }
private:
    bool isConsole;
};

class TextPlay
{
public:
    void consoleRefresh()
    {
        cout << " -Input Command-" << endl;
        cout << "" << endl;
        cout << "> ";
    }

    void consoleIntro()
    {
        cout << "Welcome to the console!" << endl;
        cout << "" << endl;
        consoleRefresh();

    }

    void makeCommand()
    {
        cin >> command;

        if (command == "exit")
        {

            // assets.editConsoleState(false); how would i do this
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "" << endl;
            cout << " INVALID COMMAND" << endl;
            cout << "" << endl;
        }
    }
private:
    string command;
};
```

So basically I want to cancel the while loop through the exit command put in the console, but I have no clue on how I would call a function in the `Assets` class.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `class TextPlay` could have as a member variable a reference to the `Assets` object (see code below):

```
class TextPlay {
  public:
    TextPlay(Assets &_assets) : assets(_assets) {}
    ...
  private:
    Assets &assets;
    string command;
};
```

Then your main function would become:

```
Assets assets;
TextPlay textplay(assets);

int main() {
  assets.editConsoleState(true);
  while (assets.consoleState() == true)) {
    textplay.consoleRefresh();
    textplay.makeCommand();
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: i added those things and tried to access it like this                 if (command == "exit"){
assets.editConsoleState(false);
}

Comment: @user3403795 It works fine take a look at http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/be86d6b801c4958c

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your code layout is wrong. You should not do:

```
#include "Ref.cpp"
```

Never include one `.cpp` file from another.

The class definitions should be in a header file (say, `Ref.h`) which is included from any `.cpp` file which needs to see them.

Now, you cannot "call a function in the Assets class" (unless it is a static function).  A *class* is like a blueprint for creating an object. The member functions of Assets can only be called on an object of type Assets. What you actually are trying to do is to call a function on the `assets` object (which is of type `Assets`).

Currently you have a global variable `assets`. I guess that you want to call functions on this object. If so, then you can write:

```
extern Assets assets;    // says that "assets" is the name of an Assets object defined elsewhere
assets.editConsoleState(false);
```

This will work, however it is a poor design. But when you are beginning C++ it is difficult to come up with good class designs. You need a bit of experience in coding to realize why bad designs are bad, and what's good about good designs. So don't worry about it too much for now.

It would be an improvement to have your class definitions just contain method declarations; and have the method bodies in `.cpp` files. You can also put `extern Assets assets;` in the header file that defines `Assets`; then the compiler will be able to enforce that `assets` is actually an `Assets`.